# Problem with variance of a function

Tags: statistics

I got a problem calculating the variance for a function. I calculated the expected value correctly, but cannot get the variance correct. my problem and solution is as follows:
[image: sol]
can someone please tell me what am i doing wrong. Thanks

Comment: $1/6 \neq 0.125$ as $0.125 = 1/8$

Comment: Yes.  Everything is right until the very end. $\frac 1 6~=~0.1\dot{6}$